Do we say "I haven't gone through" or "I haven't been through"?
I've just stumbled upon this grammar error on stackoverflow:

Didn't went through whole code

The error is obvious, but I hesitate between 2 corrections:

I haven't gone through the whole code
I haven't been through the whole code

I would say the first one, as the second one seems to be more for expressions like:

I've never been to Italy
I've already been to Italy


What about "I didn't go through the whole code"?

No, you would use that for yesterday, or last week. The context is someone who has just read a post and is answering.

Where are you getting "yesterday, or last week" from? "I didn't do..." simply means it hasn't been done. It might not have been done 20 seconds ago (as any child caught red handed would claim "I didn't do it!").

I was referring to the grammatical difference between simple past and present perfect.

Forms like "I have(n't) been through the procedure" or "...document" are common so I don't see why "been through the code" would be any different. It's possible for 2 things to be correct.

A duplicate of '... have been through ...' or '...have gone through ...?

FYI, "whole code" is a little off. Try "all of the code" or "the whole codebase".


I hesitate between 2 corrections:

I haven't gone through the whole code

I haven't been through the whole code



They are all but indistinguishable in their forms and meanings: both are correct and idiomatic.
The use of “have been” in “I have not been through the whole code” references one of the Old English verbs that joined to give our Modern English verb “to be”. That verb was -> būan to inhabit, to live, dwell, e.g. “I’ve been in Paris for 5 years now” but it had a very broad meaning,

:OED in the entry for “be (verb):  for another derivative of this
Indo-European base in English compare Old English būan to inhabit, to
live, dwell: see big v.1).

and for "to big"

OED: To big
I.3. transitive (reflexive and in passive). To establish oneself in a
location, take up one's position; to be located or established in a
place. Obsolete.

a1425 (c1333–52) Bigges him right by ȝowre side. [my translation: “He took up a position to your right”] L. Minot, Poems (1914) 28


Here, “I have not been through the whole code” can be approximated to “I have not spent time remaining (or located) inside/within the whole code.”

To me both are correct:
I haven't been through the whole code.
I haven't gone through the whole code.
Both indicate that up to the present moment I have not been/gone through, checked, reviewed, examined, the whole code. That's to say we are still within the same time period.
This implies that you may still have the intention to do so, or at least the opportunity to do so, as the time period is not yet finished.
I did not go through the whole code means that that you did not do so in a time period which is now finished.
I did not go through the whole code yesterday/this morning/ when I had the chance/ before it was published etc.
Note that you cannot say I did not be through the whole code. Or for that matter, I will not be through the whole code or I am not being through the whole code although the following are both correct.
I am not going through the whole code.
I will not go through the whole code.
Likewise;
I did not check/examine/review the whole code.
I am not checking/examining/reviewing the whole code.
I will not check/examine/review the whole code.
are all correct.
